# Getting points from html table with php

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have to automate a process where a bunch of notes about a new version of a product are taken from the main page and put them somewhere else. I can easily connect to the page I have to get it from, but I don't know how to pick this list of notes up and preferably put them in an array or list so I can use them somewhere else. this is what the html page looks like(the part that matters anyway):

```
<!-- START SUMMARY -->
<ul>
    <li>Point 1</li>
    <li>Point 2</li>
    <li>Point 3</li>
</ul>
<!-- END SUMMARY -->
```

It always starts with an "START SUMMARY" comment and ends with a "END SUMMARY" comment as well. and the number of points could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you mean that you have this "text":

```
<!-- START SUMMARY -->
<ul>
    <li>Point 1</li>
    <li>Point 2</li>
    <li>Point 3</li>
</ul>
<!-- END SUMMARY -->
```

and you will have to "parse" it with PHP in order to view if on the webpage a new Point has been added right?

In php it's helpful the function preg_split and then iterate over the returned array:

```
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $subject) as $line){
   //here you can loop over each line and you your LOGIC
}
```

Where subject is your text (it can be your whole page and then parse line by line).

IS THAT what you were looking for?

Comment: yeah, preg_split seems like a really good idea. I'll try that right now. Thanks a lot